# (tablayout) Tabs come over the keyboard when editText is focused

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have setUp `tabLayout` with ViewPager which has 5 `Fragments`. 
`tabLayout` with `android:layout_gravity` set to `bottom` . Third fragment has `editText` which when focused , my tabs come over the keyboard.

[Tablayout without EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZG3y.png)

[TabLayout with EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoDN7.png)

**Main layout :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <include
              android:id="@+id/t"
             layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"

    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout></android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Third Fragment layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:hint="Enter something"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 11):

Open **AndroidManifest.xml** and add to your activity tag
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

If this doesn't work add 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`

This will prevent the soft keyboard from adjusting the layout.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put The `TabLayout` under the `ToolBar` and aove the `ViewPager`

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380668/how-to-set-android-tablayout-in-the-bottom-of-the-screen