# Want to set Tabs in Bottom with the help of following code

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

In my application i set `Navigation Drawer` and `Tabs`
the following code is for `Tabs` and i am trying to fixed in bottom but it is not working at all.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>



</LinearLayout>
```

I want to set `Tabs` in **bottom** can anyone tell me how to set `Tabs` in Bottom using this code?

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380668/how-to-set-android-tablayout-in-the-bottom-of-the-screen

Comment: @Ironman thank you so much it is working perfectly... and can we set an icon instead of text? and should i post my java code for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change order in the LinearLayout. Viewpager will up and TabLayout will be down.

After that viewpager need to give weight property to 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        android:background="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/orange"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i already got it from the above link... but now i want to set an icon instead of  text. so can u please suggest me the answer?

Comment: I already gave answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39488685/2900893