# How to set Image/Icon in Tabs instead of Text?

Tags: android, tabs, fragment

I want to set image/icon in `Tabs`in the following code:
in my application i set `Tabs` in Bottom and now i want to set image in the space of the text.. i tried tutorials also but not getting output as i wanted to

Here **Tab.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now **Tab.Java**

```
    package com.example.sachin.navigationwithswipe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class TabFragment extends Fragment {
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));


        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
                   }
        });
        return x;

    }
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
          switch (position){
              case 0 : return new PrimaryFragment();
              case 1 : return new SocialFragment();
              case 2 : return new UpdatesFragment();
          }
        return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Primary";
                case 1 :
                    return "Social";
                case 2 :
                    return "Updates";
            }
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

i want to set Image in the `Tabs` using following code.

Comment: Refer this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this to set icon in tab

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

//You tab icons
private int[] icons = {
        R.drawable.one,
        R.drawable.two,
        R.drawable.three
};

for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(icons[i]);
}
```

Also If you want only Icon then on Adapter pass pageTitle null

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    // return null to display only the icon
    return null;
}
```

Use this for Selector. This Might Work

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_on" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon_off"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: set image ids in icons array.

Comment: yup its working perfect.... if we want to change the color of that image is it possible? like we take 2 images and then make a .xml in drawable and we directly call like R.drawable.abc.xml???

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_selected"
  android:state_selected="true" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_normal" />
</selector> like this???

Comment: yeah Go with that

Answer (score 1):

Set icon like this way..

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon));
```

Answer (score 1):

**To set both icon and text:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.ic_tab_favourite,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_call,
            R.drawable.ic_tab_contacts
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**Setting only icon to tab is same as setting text and icon except the method getPageTitle() in ViewPagerAdapter class returns null instead of tab label.**

Modify MainActivity.java and modify the `getPageTitle()` method as :

```
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    // return null to display only the icon
    return null;
}
```