# Fragments change using tabs/bottomnavigation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, tabs

First of all, I'm new in Android.

I tried to use Fragments with Bottom-Navigation and my question is, every time I change my `Fragment` (for example, fragment1 -> fragment2) my tabs doesn't change with the change in `Fragment` and everything I did in fragment1 is not saved.

To make it clearer:

I got bottom navigation bar/tab (I'm not sure what to call it). In that bar I have got 3 tabs (For example; chats, profile and contacts).

1. First I go to the profile tab and change something (for example my name). Then I go to the contacts and when I come back to the profile tab, the name that I changed earlier isn't there. It goes back to the information previously saved.

How can I save this information? Do I have to write all the information in the database and read it every time I open the profile fragment? Is it even possible?

Or can I save it in the `SharedPreference` or somewhere else? Please give me some advice with example code so that I can understand..

2. For example, I have a button in profile fragment and with this button it will change to chat fragment.

   FragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,fragmentTwo).commit();

When I do this, my fragment changes to another fragment, but my tabs in navigation bar doesn't change and it remains in the profile tab.

3. Last Question. If I change my fragment what kind of function it does run? I mean there are `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, `onActivityCreated` etc. and how can I understand how every function runs. After each other with that sequence.

Please help. I'm stuck for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can simply use the `ViewPager` along with a `TabLayout`. To get a bottom navigation bar using `TabLayout` please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33381112/3145960). The information that you edited in the profile fragment should stay in the profile fragment as you're not replacing the current fragment with another when you're using the `TabLayout`.
2. While implementing `TabLayout` using `ViewPager` you do not have to be worried about making transactions among your Fragments anymore as they are already populated when the `Activity` was loaded. You'll be handling the fragment transactions via `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
3. To understand the lifecycle of a `Fragment` you need to check the docs in the [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). See the Creating a Fragment section for better understanding in which sequence the functions are being called.

Implementing `TabLayout` in your application is fairly simple. Please check the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) for better understanding. Hope that helps.