# Swipeable Tabs with toolbar instead of actionbar

Tags: android, tabs, android-toolbar

Im developing an app for school purposes. Is it possible to create a swipeable tabs with toolbar instead of using an  actionbar? Coz i've change my style theme into NoActionbar and i dont know now how to add tablayout :( Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs

Comment: Hello there @Androider. Thanks for the response. I have red from the link that you've given me that "I have not enough time to continue developing at this time and the android design support library implements the tabs features in the better way, so I think it is useless now." Is there any other way ? thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31698756/remove-line-break-in-tablayout/32547335#32547335

Comment: For tabs on the bottom: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984706/how-can-i-set-tabs-at-the-bottom-and-also-hide-top-actionbar/32985326#32985326

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Nugent. this is a good help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try embed the TabLayout in the ToolBar like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                                           android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And then setup every thing in java code as

```
Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(null);

 String[] tabs={
        "Tab_1","Tab_2","Tab_3"
};

TabLayout tabLayout=(TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

for(String name:tabs){
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(name));
}
```

Hope this is helpful