# Bottom tabs to existing application

Tags: android, user-interface, tabs

We have an existing application which is built on activities, we want to add bottom tabs in the application, is there any open source tabs library which we can utilised? i have found few but they work with Fragments not activities. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't do tabs with Activities anymore.  Converting each Activity to a Fragment shouldn't be too hard.  See here for bottom tabs with a TabLayout, which is what you should use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984706/how-can-i-set-tabs-at-the-bottom-and-also-hide-top-actionbar

Comment: thanks @DanielNugent